# Light brown chalky Anthurium leaf is it interveinal chlorosis?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, aroid

I'm new to this stack community so please be nice.
There is a light brown chalky color on my *Anthurium*'s leaves its not an obvious fungus structure the best I can determine is that it's something like interveinal chlorosis but I wouldn't know. Please note the brown spots on the edge of the leaves isn't my concern it's the rest of the leaf that I'm talking about.

[image: Leaf with discoloration]

[image: Close-up of leaf]

[image: Underside of leaf]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A closeup picture of the underside of the leaf would help. However you can do my diagnosis:

- check a few leaves this way
- carefully turn a leaf over and look closely
- do you see small insects the size of an exclamation mark?
- or do you see small white larvae like a small exclamation mark?
- or do you see small white grains the size of salt?

If you see the first two then I think you have [thrip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrips). See [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=thrip)
or it is less likely you have [spider mites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_mite)  see [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=spider%20mite%20isaccepted%3Ayes)

If it's thrip they are extremely hard to control as the kids live inside the leaf tissue.  Just throw the plant out.

Spider mite can be controlled with 5ml dish soap and 1 liter of water applied every 5 to 6 days at least three times

Comment: ok i added more pics please see

Comment: after looking at the second image in this article;s section on "Anthurium"  i can conclude it is spider mite https://135artnature.ru/en/spider-mite-and-fight-with-it-spider-mite-fighting-and-preparing-a-greenhouse-for-the-season.html
I will treat it soon thanks

Comment: @TechnoloJesus  Mites can be controlled, cut back the worst leaves, wipe the rest with soap and water